# Solderless breadboards: standard size specifications?

Tags: breadboard, standard

Are there standard sizes for solderless breadboards?

For example, My teaching project is currently reaching the capacity limit of a 170 pin (17 x 10) breadboard.  Is there a standard "next size larger" I can specify?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various de facto standard sizes.

[Tiny](http://www.adafruit.com/products/65) (170 tie points)

[image]

[Half-sized](http://www.adafruit.com/product/64) (400 tie points)

[image]

[Full-sized](http://www.adafruit.com/products/239) (830 tie points)

[image]

Larger (with or without doubled power rails)

[image: Double, double rails]
[image: Quad, single rails, double rails along top]

Note that spacing from breadboard to breadboard over a single rail is 700mil.

Comment: Different vendors have different layout. Some use single power rails along the sides, some have 6 tie points in a row others have 5. I don't think there really is such a thing as standard sizes, rather than vendors setting their own.

Comment: Sure, *some* vendors vary from these formats. But if you go into any store that sells breadboards it is *extremely* likely that they will have one or more of the sizes listed here.

Comment: A point to note here is that most solderless breadboards,  including some "tiny" [170-point boards](http://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J2074.1200.jpg), are designed to be clipped together to make bigger breadboards. In [some cases](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/ad-101-breadboard-ag09k) you can unclip power-rails or clip on extra power-rails.

Answer (score 0):

The breadboard you show is probably the smallest available.  I think the most common size is about 6.5 inches long, and has long power busses along both sides.  There may be intermediate sizes, but I have had no reason to look for other sizes.